# Flexible filtered list of data in combobox depending on another (previous) combobox selection

Tags: java, combobox

I have two comboboxes that contain locations: 
[1st combobox lists the cities. 2nd combobox lists the pronvices in the city. So the values that should be listed in the 2nd combobox is dependent on the 1st combobox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLkCo.jpg)

I get the values from mysql database. This is my code:

```
locList1 = new ArrayList<Locations_Master>();  
    locList1 = locDAO.getLM(); //contains the list of all Cities and Barangays from database

    cityS1 = "";
    citySL1 = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i<locList1.size(); i++){
        cityS1 = locList1.get(i).getCity() + "\n";
        citySL1.add(cityS1);
    }
    cityList1 = new JComboBox(citySL1.toArray());
    cityList1.setBounds(5, 110, 170, 20);
    mainPanel.add(cityList1);
    cityList1.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
            selectedCity = cityList1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            mainPanel.validate();
            mainPanel.repaint();

        }
    });
    barSL1 = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<locList1.size(); i++){ 
        if(locList1.get(i).getCity().equals(selectedCity)){
            barS1 = locList1.get(i).getBarangay()+"\n";
            barSL1.add(barS1); 
        //I tried filtering the barangay values here dependent on the selected city

        }
        System.out.println(barSL1);
    }
    barList1 = new JComboBox(barSL1.toArray());
    barList1.setBounds(185, 110, 170, 20);
    mainPanel.add(barList1);
```

Suuposedly, every time the user selects a city, the barangays listed under the city should be shown. There is no "error" in the output, but barSL1 is [] as seen in the output.

Answer (score 0):

what you should actually need is an action to be called when user selects the citylist comboBox. You can use addPopupMenuListener interface for that function.
So whenever user click on an item in the popupmenu of the combobox the events will be called. by getting out the selected value in cityList combo you can then adjust the province combobox.

```
 cityList1.addPopupMenuListener(new actionCombo());

 class actionCombo implements PopupMenuListener{

        @Override
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
         String cityname = combo1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            adjustProvince(cityname);
        }

        @Override
        public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {

        }

  } 

 public void adjustProvince(String cityName){
 province.addItem(cityName);
 }
```

you can complete `adjustProvince()` method to set data in province combo box.